# get list of all checked boxes in a Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I have a list view of check boxes, created by the fallowing.

```
    public void addCard(final String cardId){
    ListView listView1;
    Lists movielist = new Lists();
    List<String> movies = new ArrayList<String>();      
    movies = movielist.movieList();

    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, movies));
    listView1.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);



    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


    CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)arg1;        
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ctv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //do your stuff in here!        
    }   
    });

    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
     });
}
```

Now when an box is check I can toast the Text associated with the check-box. What I would like to be able to do is toast the text associated with all of the boxes that are checked upon clicking submit.

Ideally I would like a List which each value being one of the chucks of text associated with a check-box.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked views are returned in SparseBooleanArray, so you might use the below code to get key or values.The below sample are simply displayed selected names in a single String.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
{

       SparseBooleanArray sp=getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

     String str="";
       for(int i=0;i<sp.size();i++)
       {
           str+=movies.get(sp.keyAt(i))+",";
        }
      Toast.makeText(this, ""+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
```

I think this is what you want.